# Separate index, column, and value in symmetric Pandas dataframe into three different columns without duplication

Tags: python, pandas

Currently, my df looks like:

```
    a   b   c   
a   0   7   9  
b   7   0   3  
c   9   3   0
```

I would like to make the column and index pair, and corresponding value, into three separate columns, but in a way that doesn't repeat pairs (since it's symmetric):

```
column   index   value
a        a       0
a        b       7
a        c       9     
b        b       0
b        c       3
c        c       0
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use

```
df=df.where(np.triu(np.ones(df.shape)).astype(np.bool)).stack().reset_index()
  level_0 level_1    0
0       a       a  0.0
1       a       b  7.0
2       a       c  9.0
3       b       b  0.0
4       b       c  3.0
5       c       c  0.0
```

Or we do `melt` with `np.sort` then drop the `duplicate`

```
s=df.reset_index().melt('index')
s[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(s[['index','variable']],axis=1)).duplicated().values]
  index variable  value
0     a        a      0
1     b        a      7
2     c        a      9
4     b        b      0
5     c        b      3
8     c        c      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Create [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) of the letters ("abc"), and reindex the dataframe after `stacking`

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(combinations_with_replacement("abc",2),
                                      names=["columns","index"])

new_index

MultiIndex([('a', 'a'),
            ('a', 'b'),
            ('a', 'c'),
            ('b', 'b'),
            ('b', 'c'),
            ('c', 'c')],
           names=['columns', 'index'])

#reindex
df.stack().reindex(new_index).reset_index(name='value')


 columns     index  value
0   a           a   0
1   a           b   7
2   a           c   9
3   b           b   0
4   b           c   3
5   c           c   0
```